# text Gradient color shadow not display properly in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, gradient

I'm displaying text in gradient color. it displays but when I display that text in gradient color it does not display properly.

it displays like this.

[image]

this is my code

To apply gradient color. I Give 5,5 offset

```
class GradientText extends StatelessWidget {
  const GradientText(
    this.text, {
    required this.gradient,
    this.style,
  });

  final String text;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final Gradient gradient;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn,
      shaderCallback: (bounds) => gradient.createShader(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height),
      ),
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: style,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

apply shadow color to text

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: MyTheme.mytheme.shade50,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [
Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: GradientText("Wallpaper",
                    style: GoogleFonts.pacifico(
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30, shadows: [
                      Shadow(
                        blurRadius: 10,
                        offset: Offset(5, 5),
                      )
                    ])),
                    gradient: const LinearGradient(colors: [
                      Colors.red,
                      Colors.pink,
                      Colors.purple,
                      Colors.deepPurple,
                      Colors.indigo,
                      Colors.blue,
                      Colors.lightBlue,
                      Colors.cyan,
                      Colors.teal,
                      Colors.green,
                      Colors.lightGreen,
                      Colors.lime,
                      Colors.yellow,
                      Colors.amber,
                      Colors.orange,
                      Colors.deepOrange,
                    ])),
              )
            ],
          )
    ])
  )
)
```

So how can I display the shadow of text properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `Text` with `Padding` will fix this issue:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class GradientText extends StatelessWidget {
  const GradientText(
      this.text, {
        required this.gradient,
        this.style,
      });

  final String text;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final Gradient gradient;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn,
      shaderCallback: (bounds) => gradient.createShader(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height),
      ),
      child: Padding( //add this widget
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), //add this widget
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: style,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```